# sql stored procedure order-by issue

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have following simple stored procedure when I try to call this procedure using mysql command-line it returns result in ascending order always.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `activity_pagin_desc`(
    IN `payload_context_id` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `tenant_domain` VARCHAR(100),
    IN `order_val` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `lim_val` INT,
    IN `lim_offset` INT
)
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    FROM SOCIAL_COMMENTS
    WHERE payload_context_id=payload_context_id AND tenant_domain=tenant_domain
    ORDER BY order_val DESC
    LIMIT lim_val OFFSET lim_offset;
END
//
```

What I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You're saying `ASC` and `DESC` return the query in the same order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `order_val` is a constant.  So, ascending or descending doesn't matter.  You can use dynamic SQL, or multiple `case` statements:

```
order by (case when order_val = 'col1' then col1 end),
         (case when order_val = 'col2' then col2 end),
         . . .
```

The multiple `case` statements are useful because the logic will work regardless of the different types of the columns that are referenced.